# Error authorizing OAuth access token - 400 Client Error: Bad Request

Tags: apache-superset

I am trying to connect zitadel with superset 2.1. But after user authentication, I am getting an error in the superset. I have configured the zitadel application/client to use PKCE method for openid. Do anybody have any idea on this error?
I configured the zitadel authentication using superset documentation https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset/#custom-oauth2-configuration

The error received is the below:

ERROR:flask_appbuilder.security.views:Error authorizing OAuth access token: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.com:443/oauth/v2/token

I need to resolve this error and the superset need to be authenticated using zitadel